# How to make td field type password

Tags: php, html, sql

I'm a complete beginner with this so if someone could help me that would be awesome!

How to make the 4th row ( `$row[3]` ) field type password?

```
 <?php

$sql = "SELECT * FROM users ORDER BY id ASC";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    echo "<tr><td>" . $row["0"]. "</td><td>" . $row[1]. "</td><td>" . $row[2]."</td><td><input type='password' value=' . $row[3].' readonly='readonly'>""</td><td>" . $row[4] . "</td><td>" . $row[5] . "</td>
        <td>
        <a class='btn btn-success' href='edituser.php?id=" . $row[0] . "'>Update</a>
        </td>";
}
?>
```

Comment: If i am reading this correct, it is of type password but it's also readonly, so you will never be able to type in it.

Comment: `<td><input type='password' value='" . $row[3]."'></td>`

Answer (score 2):

You just need to fix the `readonly` issue. The double quote by `<td>` is not needed.

```
 <?php

$sql = "SELECT * FROM users ORDER BY id ASC";

$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
echo "<table>"; #add this
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    echo "<tr>"
    . "<td>" . $row["0"] . "</td>"
    . "<td>" . $row[1] . "</td>"
    . "<td>" . $row[2] . "</td>"
    . "<td>"
    . "<input type='password' value='" . $row[3] . "'readonly='readonly'></td>"
    . "<td>" . $row[4] . "</td>"
    . "<td>" . $row[5] . "</td>"
    . "<td>
        <a class='btn btn-success' href='edituser.php?id=" . $row[0] . "'>Update</a>
        </td> </tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
?>
```

I also suggest you download an IDE like Netbeans or PHPStorm. It'll help solve this type of issues.

Answer (score 0):

helpfull

```
<?php
                        $sql = "SELECT * FROM users ORDER BY id ASC";

                        $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
                        echo "<table>"  
                        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) 
                        {
                        echo "<tr><td>" . $row["0"]. "</td><td>" . $row[1]. "</td><td>" . $row[2]."</td><td><input type='password' value='" . $row[3]."'readonly='readonly'>""</td><td>" . $row[4]. "</td><td>" . $row[5]."</td>
                        <td>
                        <a class='btn btn-success' href='edituser.php?id=".$row[0]."'>Update</a>
                        </td> </tr>";
                        }
echo "</table>"

                      ?>
```

Answer (score -2):

okay .. it was very simple...

```
<?php
                        $sql = "SELECT * FROM users ORDER BY id ASC";

                        $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
                        echo "<table>"  
                        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) 
                        {
                        echo "<tr><td>" . $row["0"]. "</td><td>" . $row[1]. "</td><td>" . $row[2]."</td><td><input type='password' value='" . $row[3]."'readonly='readonly'>""</td><td>" . $row[4]. "</td><td>" . $row[5]."</td>
                        <td>
                        <a class='btn btn-success' href='edituser.php?id=".$row[0]."'>Update</a>
                        </td> </tr>";
                        }
echo "</table>"

                      ?>
```

follow and analyze this code, and you will find the mistake , and definitely it will help you

Comment: Why do you need so much indentation?

Comment: main problem is:                                                                                    <input type='password' value= **'" . $row[3]."'** readonly='readonly'>

Comment: and you can also use online php validators to know whats wrong.. ;)

Comment: "_and you will find the mistake_" Found it: `value='" . $row[3]."'readonly=`